# Is it possible to transfer data from several specific cells in Excel to a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I'm trying to set up a Word Template able to copy several building details from an Excel spreadsheet and paste them onto the document. There is a column for each detail such as **Address** and **"Size"**. I would like to know if this Word template could pull these details in a specific order like "The following property is located at **Address** measuring approximately **Size** built in **Year of Construction** or something of sorts.

I currently do this manually by copying and pasting every detail but it takes a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Is there a reason why copy and paste wouldn't work? I assume there is, but it might help if you edit your question to explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: Oh, yes of course, I'll edit the question. Copying and pasting is actually the method I'm using right now but it just simply takes too long because there is too much info and I have to repeat this process every single time. I was thinking on setting up a template and have it pull all of the information at once and save time I just don't know how. I assume it involves VBA and some Macro work but I wouldn't know where to start with that

Comment: If data is already in columns in Excel spreadsheet, can you not use Word's mail merge feature to import the specific text you want?